# How do I create an artifact in IntelliJ IDEA like "activator dist"

Tags: intellij-idea, typesafe-activator

I used to compile my Play2 project with lightbend activator and now moved to the IntelliJ IDEA IDE.
I did create an IntelliJ project using the activator and managed to compile and run/debug the project.
What I could not achive is to create a file for deployment like "activator dist" would create.

Is there a way to import the dist target as an artifact or is there a another way to create a similar package for deployment with IntelliJ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to build a quite dist package by using the sbt console and the "dist" command